# Import and display image one by one

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# window form for importing and displaying multiple images.

I am able to import multiple images and display the first image, but got some problems on displaying images one by one.

The program flow: user click the button, then select multiple images. After that, the first image should be displayed on the picture box. When the user click the "next image button", the next image should be shown.

The first image is able to display on the picturebox but no idea on displaying them one by one. 
Is there any configuration for achieving this or how to implement it through coding.
Thanks everyone.

My coding:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeOpenFileDialog();
    }

    private void InitializeOpenFileDialog()
    {
        // Set the file dialog to filter for graphics files. 
        this.openFileDialog1.Filter =
            "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF|" +
            "All files (*.*)|*.*";

        // Allow the user to select multiple images. 
        this.openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
        this.openFileDialog1.Title = "My Image Browser";
    }

    private void SelectFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Read the files 
            foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                // Create a PictureBox. 
                    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                    Image loadedImage = Image.FromFile(file);
                    pb.Height = loadedImage.Height;
                    pb.Width = loadedImage.Width;
                    pb.Image = loadedImage;
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll be able to see what the problem is better by inserting a try catch inside the SelectFileButton_Click eventhandler, please see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, there is a better way for achieving that.

You don't have to add `PictureBox` control for **each** image, it will overload your form.
My suggestion is to keep a list of all loaded images, and an indexer of the current shown image.

**Code:**

Add a `PictureBox` to your form (let's call it `pictureBox1`), where you want the images to shown.

In addition, add these properties to your class:

```
private List<Image> loadedImages = new List<Image>();
private int currentImageIndex;
```

In your "load images" button click event:

```
private void SelectFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        loadedImages.Clear();

        // Read the files 
        foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
        {
            // Create a PictureBox. 
            loadedImages.Add(Image.FromFile(file));
        }

        if (loadedImages.Count > 0)
        {
            currentImageIndex = 0;
            pictureBox1.Image= loadedImages[currentImageIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, for Next/Previous buttons click event you can add this code:

```
// Mod function to support negative values (for the back button).
int mod(int a, int b)
{
    return (a % b + b) % b;
}

// Show the next picture in the PictureBox.
private void button_next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentImageIndex = mod(currentImageIndex + 1, loadedImages.Count);
    pictureBox1.Image = loadedImages[currentImageIndex];
}

// Show the previous picture in the PictureBox.
private void button_prev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentImageIndex = mod(currentImageIndex - 1, loadedImages.Count);
    pictureBox1.Image = loadedImages[currentImageIndex];
}
```